# Wordpress upgrade adding additional quote marks to shortcode output

Tags: shortcode

Since upgrade to 4.1.1, Some shortcodes are now playing up.  IE The HTML output.

Below is in the functions file for producing TABS.

```
/*******************************************************************
Tabs
********************************************************************/   
function slicetheme_tabs($atts, $content = null)
{   
   if (!preg_match_all("/(.?)\[(item)\b(.*?)(?:(\/))?\](?:(.+?)\[\/item\])?(.?)/s",   $content, $matches)) {
    return do_shortcode($content);
}
else
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++) {
        $matches[3][$i] = shortcode_parse_atts($matches[3][$i]);
    }

    $out = '<div class="st-tabs">';     
        $out.= '<ul class="tab-title unstyled">';
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++) {
            $attstoclass = !empty($matches[3][$i]['icon']) ? '<i class="'. $matches[3]  [$i]['icon'] .'"></i> ' : '';
            $out.= '<li><a href="#tab-'. $i .'">'. $attstoclass . $matches[3][$i]['title'] .'</a></li>';
        }
        $out.= '</ul>';     
        $out.= '<div class="tab-container">';
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++) {
            $out.= '<div id="tab-'. $i .'" class="tab-content">'. wpautop( do_shortcode(trim($matches[5][$i])) ) .'</div>';
        }
        $out.= '</div>';
    $out.= '</div>';
    return $out;
}

}
add_shortcode('tabs', 'slicetheme_tabs');
```

The HTML Output of above is

```
<li><a href="#tab-0"><i class="&#8221;icon-user&#8221;"></i> &#8221;Project</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab-1"><i class="&#8221;icon-comments&#8221;"></i> &#8221;Acknowledgements&#8221;</a></li>
```

The code in the page is

```
[tabs] [item icon="icon-user" title="Project Description"]
```

So as you can see, its not only adding extra quotes, it's also not display the second worD?  IE PROJECT instead PROJECT DESCRIPTION

All from a theme that is not supported anymore - but its a good theme to continue to use if I can fix this code.

Cheers

Comment: Piece of code which is not supported !== good code to use

Comment: Sorry Mark, dunno what/where you mean -  !== good code to use

Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: If it is not supported it means that there will not be security updates, and no adaptations for future wordpress features, and no one to advice you if you run into a problem. If you can "own" the code and manage it by yourself then there is no real problem with that, but some code packages are just to big for that. An example I can come up with right now is jquery. If jQuery dies there is no way that I will be able to hack a library that size when needed, and I will prefer to move to other library that is actively maintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the result of the wordpress 4.0.1 security fix which changed how shortcodes are handled http://wptavern.com/wordpress-4-0-1-exposes-bad-development-practices-used-in-some-plugins. While I am not sure about the details your shortcode handling seems to match the general description of trying to parse the shortcode by yourself instead of properly registering it.

To fix this you need to create, register and handle an "item" shortcode.

Comment: Thx Mark - Howver everything was fine in 4.0.1..  Only since upgrade to 4.1.1?

Comment: Your code is not written to the standarts of the wordpress API, one day it might work and the other is might break. backwark and forward compatibility is attempted (assured is just too strong word, but this is the word you should think of) only for code that follows the API and API guidlines